# How to make my Custom Model Parcelable with custom object in it's Constructor

Tags: java, android, parcelable, custom-object

This is my class that I'm trying to make it Parcelable, As you can see in code I Stuck in some places in code:

```
public class CommentModel implements Parcelable{

    String      COMMENT_CONTENT;
    String      COMMENT_ID;
    UserModel   COMMENT_ACTOR;

    public CommentModel(String comment_content, String comment_id, UserModel comment_user){

        this.COMMENT_CONTENT    = comment_content;
        this.COMMENT_ID         = comment_id;
        this.COMMENT_ACTOR      = comment_user;

    }

    /*== constructor to rebuild object from the Parcel ==*/
    public CommentModel(Parcel source) {

        this.COMMENT_CONTENT                = source.readString();
        this.COMMENT_ID                     = source.readString();

        // This is where I'm stuck!
        this.COMMENT_ACTOR                  = source............;
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return this.COMMENT_CONTENT;
    }

    public void setContent(String content){
        this.COMMENT_CONTENT    = content;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.COMMENT_ID;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.COMMENT_ID = id;
    }

    public UserModel getActor(){
        return this.COMMENT_ACTOR;
    }

    public void setActor(UserModel actor){
        this.COMMENT_ACTOR  = actor;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(COMMENT_CONTENT);
        dest.writeString(COMMENT_ID);

        // This is where I'm stuck too! :(
        dest.write.....
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CommentModel> CREATOR = new Creator<CommentModel>() {

        @Override
        public CommentModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CommentModel[size];
        }

        @Override
        public CommentModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CommentModel(source);
        }
    };


}
```

How should do it?
Is It possible totally? if not how can handle this issue?

P.s: My UserModel() is Parcelable too of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `UserModel` is `Parcelable`, you can use [writeParcelable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeParcelable(android.os.Parcelable,%20int)) to write the object and [readParcelable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readParcelable(java.lang.ClassLoader)) to read it back. E.g.

```
dest.writeParcelable(COMMENT_ACTOR, flages);
```

to write, and

```
COMMENT_ACTOR = source.readParcelable(UserModel.class.getClassLoader());
```

to read it back.